# what to commit in XCode (5.0.2) project - Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

I cannot find some other related questions or articles.

I am sharing my iPhone app project (Xcode) with my friends by subversion system (svn)

And, When I am trying to commit the new programs, I cannot figure out what is the correct files I have to commit.

1. New classes (.h & .m)
2. New framework (this is the common existing framework provided by apple)

So far, I added a new framework into XCode (5.0.2) project & one class (.h & m) under sub-directory (e.g. Test) of "Classes".

I simply committed the new classes. But, it never come out on XCode project's view.
So, I think I am missing some files to be committed.
Also, I cannot figure out what files which import new framework.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? You can't commit classes, only files. Did you also commit the Xcode project? (It's a bundle with additional files inside it.) Generally, you don't need to commit Apple frameworks as they'll be on all developer's machines.

Comment: Oh-, I commited class files, e.g. Test.h & Test.m files. Xcode project means something like test.xcodeproj? My friends are using different provisioning. And, I am worried that I might overrwrite his provisioning settings also. So, any case, I have to commit test.codeproj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should commit everything in the project directory, without the user data folder found under `.xcodeproj > xcuserdata`. You can add this folder to the ignore list, so other people don't commit it either. The user data folder contains non-shared schemes and private settings, such as state, history, etc., so it is safe to ignore it and not commit.

[Here is the ignore list by GitHub for Xcode](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore). You will not find all of these folders, and indeed, in most cases, the xcuserdata is the only folder you need to worry about.

Comment: What about something like build settings? Because we are different versions. So, if I commit .xcodeproj, my build settings are also reflected, right? I just want to make the new class appears & add the new framework in the project. So, now, I cannot avoid committing all files?

Comment: Yes, build settings should be shared between the users. Build settings, such as what files to compile and how, as well as which libraries and frameworks to link against, are found in .xcodeproj.

Comment: Actually, I think you might feel weird why we don't use the same XCode version. But, I dont want to care about  Xcode version

Comment: You don't have to worry about different Xcode versions. `.xcodeproj` has not changed in a long time and should not really cause trouble.